# How to change html in a AJAX loaded page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using AJAX to load a PHP page into a div called 'DIV1' In there it creates a part of table and in there is another div called 'directions' I want to be able to change the contents of the 'directions' div but cant seem to find it? Is it because its dynamic? I have tried several things and will show example, but where am I going wrong?

The code for the AJAX load is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainstuff button").click(function(){
        $('#loader').show();
        status = $(this).attr("data-name");
        var new_url = "get_job_details3.php?job_id="+status;
        //alert(status);
        $("#div1").load(new_url);           
    });
});
```

The part of the PHP that generates the table where the 'directions' div is like so :

```
echo "<input style='display:none' id='p_lat' type='text' value='".$p_lat."'><input style='display:none' id='p_lng' type='' value='".$p_lng."'><input style='display:none' id='d_lat' type='text' value='".$d_lat."'><input style='display:none' id='d_lng' type='' value='".$d_lng."'><table class='mainTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>


<td width='50%' style='vertical-align: top'><li>Vehicle required : <B>".$vehicle_required."</B></li>$r<li>Pick up time : <B>".$new_date."</B></li><li>Pick up time : <B>".$p_time."</B></li><li>Pick up address : <B>".$p_address."</B></li><li>Destination address : <B>".$d_address."</B></li><li>Return date : <B>".$d_date_new."</B></li><li>Return time : <B>".$d_time."</B></li><li>Number of passengers : <B>".$pax."</B></li><li>Estimated distance : <B>".$est_dist."</B></li><li>Estimated time : <B>".$est_time."</B></li><li></li><div id='mymap'><li><button id='show_map' style='margin-right:10px' type='button' class='btn btn-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></span> SHOW ON MAP </button><button id='show_directions' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#directions' type='button' class='btn btn-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker'></span> SHOW DIRECTIONS </button><div id='directions' class='collapse'>Lorem ipsum dolor text....</div></li></td>
<td width='50%' id='description'><li>Purpose : <B>".$purpose."</B></li><li>Extra requirements : <B>".$list."</B></li><li>Notes : <B>".$notes."</B></li><li>Total current bids : <B>".$total_bids."</B></li><li>Current lowest bid : <B>£".$lowest_bid_price."</B></li><li>Your bids on this job : <B>".$your_bids."</B></li><li>Your current lowest bid : <B>£".$my_lowest_bid."</B></li><li>Make a new bid of : £<input id='bid_amount' type='text'><li><textarea id='extras' class='extras' placeholder='Enter any information you would like the customer to know'></textarea></li><li><button id='make_bid' data-name='".$job_id."' type='button' class='btn btn-bid'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> MAKE BID </button><button type='button' style='float:right' class='btn btn-success' onclick='closedown()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span> CLOSE </button></li></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
```

and I am trying to update the content of the 'directions' div like so :

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('#div1 .mainTable directions'));
```

I have tried everything from 'directions' to the above. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If to target a div with _id "directions"_ your code is invalid. It should be  `directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));` ... and note, that code needs to be called _after_ the new page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) doesn't take a css selector, as it name implies it takes just the id string. You might have meant to use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which does take a css selector. Note fixed your `directions` part to actually be a id selector.

```
document.querySelector('#div1 .mainTable #directions')
//or just
document.querySelector("#directions")
```

But if you actually meant to use getElementById then just pass the element's id string:

```
document.getElementById("directions")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Patrick mentions, the `getElementById` needs to be fixed. But it also depends on when you run the code. In order to make sure you run the `setPanel` code after the server call is done, you can put it in the [success callback of the `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load#callback-function) (which runs when the load is done);

```
$("#div1").load(new_url, function () {
    // this code will run after the ajax is done
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
});
```

---

edit:

I don't know what your `setPanel` method does, but `document.getElementById('directions')` should be able to get the inserted div after the load has run.

If you just want to change its contents you could do:

```
document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = "some new text";
```

Comment: ok i understand that, but what if I just wanted to change the text in the DIV? I still cant find it??